# Finding the number of occurances of a character of each string within a list (python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, character

I'm looking for a for loop that finds the number of occurrences of a specific character(s) divided by the length of the string. after of which it shows the largest variable

```
Largestnumber=0
>>>List=["shadow", "light", "blazar"]
>>>Insert= input("input a character(s): ")
for loop
Print (Largestnumber)
```

and it will appear like this:

```
input a character(s): a#I have inputed an a
0.33333
```

Again I'm looking for a way to find the times in which a character appears in an item in the string divided by the length of the exact item.
in my example
"shadow" has one a in it and the length is 6 so it would be 1/6 = 0.1666666
"wing" doesn't have any a's within it and has the length of 4 so it would be 0/4
"blazar" has 2 a's and the length of the whole sting is 6 so 2/6 = 0.3333333
and since 0.33333 is the largest number it is printed

Comment: `'somestring'.count('s')` and `len('somestring')` may come in handy...

Comment: Just a note, that `List` is a pretty bad name for a variable, even though it doesn't conflict with the built in `list` type because of the capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

You will need five things:

1. A variable that stores the greatest ratio seen so far.
2. A variable that stores the corresponding string.
3. The for loop.
4. `'<string>'.count('<substring>')` counts how often `<substring>` appears in `<string>`. So `'blazar'.count('a')` will be 2.
5. `len(<string>)` will give you the length of `<string>`. So `len('blazar')` will be 6.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple list comprehension:

```
Largestnumber=max([float(x.count(Insert))/len(x) for x in List])
```

**EDIT**
as pointed out by @[Galax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5551669/galax)，the list comprehension can be omitted

```
Largestnumber=max(float(x.count(Insert))/len(x) for x in List)
```

Comment: If you are using a recent version of Python, there's no need for the list comprehension, this will create a generator expression: `Largestnumber=max(float(x.count(Insert))/len(x) for x in List)`